# How to use the results of a PROC REG in SAS Student

Tags: sas, regression, linear-regression

I am testing the SAS REG procedure, in the Student version. I set up the table below:

```
data work.house;
input houseSize lotSize bedrooms granite bathroom sellingPrice;
cards;
3529 9191  6 0 0 205000
3247 10061 5 1 1 224900
4032 10150 5 0 1 197900
2397 14156 4 1 0 189900
2200 9600  4 0 1 195000
3536 19994 6 1 1 325000
2983 9365  5 0 1 230000
;
run;
```

And I performed the regression analysis with the various variables, as follows:

```
proc reg data=work.HOUSE;
    model sellingPrice = houseSize lotSize bedrooms granite bathroom;
run;
```

SAS Student shows the results in a well organized and complete visual form, including many graphics.

However, I need to use the estimated parameters to forecast other inputs.

Is there any way to access these parameters?

Or is there a way to save the results (in particular the *Parameter Estimates* table) into a SAS dataset?

Comment: In general look at the OUTPUT statement to see what type of data you can save. But any output seen can be saved to a dataset, including data behind graphs, https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2017/01/09/ods-output-any-statistic.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the procedure option `OUTEST=` to save the parameter estimates.
Use `OUTPUT` statement to save the original data with predicted and residual values.

Example:

```
* output data sets highlighted with ^^^^;

proc reg noprint data=work.HOUSE outest=parameters;
*                                       ^^^^^^^^^^ ;
    model sellingPrice = houseSize lotSize bedrooms granite bathroom;
    output out=predicted p=fitprice r=fitresidual;
*              ^^^^^^^^^;
run;
quit;
```

Parameters

[image]

Predicted

[image]